# Unable to Jest spyOn File.prototype.text

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I've been struggling to understand why I cannot spy the File.prototype.text function with Jest in Typescript. I've found I can simply mock its implementation but I couldn't find a way to create an spy for it.
The following line of code works perfectly

```
File.prototype.text = jest.fn().mockImplementation(function (this: File) {
      return this;
    });
```

I'm trying to make the spy as follows:

```
jest.spyOn(File.prototype, "text").mockImplementation(function (this: File) {
  return new Promise(() => this.text);
});
```

The error given by Jest when the tests run is:

> Cannot spy on the text property because it is not a function; undefined given instead. If you are trying to mock a property, use `jest.replaceProperty(object, 'text', value)` instead.

But in the File instance in *lib.dom.d.ts* is:

```
declare var File: {
    prototype: File;
    new(fileBits: BlobPart[], fileName: string, options?: FilePropertyBag): File;
};
```

And the *File* interface is extending *Blob* interface:

```
interface Blob {
    /** [MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Blob/size) */
    readonly size: number;
    /** [MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Blob/type) */
    readonly type: string;
    /** [MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Blob/arrayBuffer) */
    arrayBuffer(): Promise<ArrayBuffer>;
    /** [MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Blob/slice) */
    slice(start?: number, end?: number, contentType?: string): Blob;
    /** [MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Blob/stream) */
    stream(): ReadableStream<Uint8Array>;
    /** [MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Blob/text) */
    text(): Promise<string>;
}
```

Which has a *text* function.

Does anyone know why Jest is detecting in runtime it *text* is not a function?
Thank you

Comment: What's the `testEnvironment` config in your `jest.config.js`?

Comment: I have some js files (babelTransform.js, cssTransform.js, fileTransform.js, resolver.js)under config/jest. Sorry I'm quite new developing with Jest. Which one do you need to check?